# utop: Error: Reference to undefined global `Grammar'

Tags: ocaml, coq, utop

I want to check the info of Coq grammar so I loaded grammar.cma into utop:

```
#load "/home/xxx/.opam/system/lib/coq/grammar/grammar.cma";;
```

but there's an error:

```
Error: Reference to undefined global `Grammar'
```

Coq version: 8.5.0
OCaml version: 4.02.3
utop version: 1.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the `Drop` command, that will actually give you access to a ML toplevel for further development.

```
$ coqtop.byte
Coq < Drop.
#
```

Documentation for `Drop`: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual008.html#hevea_command137